# URLSession: use http/1.1 instead of http/2

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I saw that URLSession supports HTTP 1.1 and HTTP 2 (`URLSession supports the HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 protocols`).

How can I enforce URLSession to use HTTP1.1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not something determined by the `URLSession`. It is determined by the server it connects to.

Read more on that here... https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94907

Comment: but if the server says that http/2 is possible can't 1.1 be enforced by the client? this is possible on Android...

Comment: @swalkner Why would you want to do that?

Comment: cause currently we're using a tool which has a bug with http/2 and we cannot force 1.1 on the server.

Comment: @swalkner ah, fair enough.

Comment: @swalkner did you manage to force the http/1.1 from the client side?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: When the server offers HTTP/2 and then has an error, but works with HTTP/1.1, one really wishes for control over the user-agent!

Comment: Hey guys, did you get any success falling back to use of http1.1? I read it depends on server but want to know if client can have ability to offer http1.1 only?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, there is ALPN negotiation to decide if HTTP/2. If client does not send ALPN, then server should not use HTTP/2.